# What can I do about a memory leak in a default vapor swift project?

Tags: swift, debugging, memory, vapor

When I generate a new vapor project:

```
vapor new test
cd test
vapor xcode -y
```

And then run this project in xcode without changing anything and then request the root route a few times using `curl`, the memory graph in the xcode debugging tools climbs up, but doesn't go back down again.

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

Is this a problem with vapor? Because it happens in the default project?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the same on Linux? Anyway that question is for vapor repo issues and their discord chat.

Answer (score 1):

Does it always keep climbing up after lots and lots of requests or does it stop after a few? The chances are it's the event loop service cache or similar, where each thread needs to instantiate various things, once they're instantiated it shouldn't keep climbing

Comment: It stops after a few requests sent quickly after each other, but starts climbing again after waiting a few minutes and then sending requests again. But what you are saying makes sense.